# Differences in the Semantics of Three Tri-Part Phrasal Verbs

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases, differences, verbs

What are the subtle semantic differences in the following three tri-part phrasal verbs:

(1) be up against
(2) come up against
(3) run up against

Comment: Not to mention *"go up against"*.

Comment: That is a little different because it means to "compete" with someone. Whereas be, come, and run up against have the meaning of facing a problem. But thanks for adding that one too!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences, I think, are mostly *aspectual* rather than *semantic*. That is,

- *be up against* tends to be used to describe the *state* of wrestling with a difficulty—“I’m up against something here I don’t know how to handle.”
- *come up against* tends to be used to describe *encountering* a difficulty. However, it is often, perhaps usually, employed in the present perfect—*We’ve come up against something we can’t handle, and we wondered if you have any ideas”—which carries the notion of a *state* created in the past but enduring into the present.
- *run up against* is not significantly different from *come up against*. I would tend to  favour it in contexts where a difficulty was encountered unexpectedly, arresting progress abruptly, as if it had overtones of “running into a brick wall”; but that’s quite possibly only a personal preference.

None of these is written in stone; they are tendencies only, and I think you may safely use any of them in any context and they will be perceived to mean exactly the same thing: you’ve got a problem.

Comment: Nice breakdown of these. Would you say "be" is a bit different than the other two?

Comment: @PatrickT.Randolph Ayup: stative v. inchoative I think are the technical terms.